# How to use subquery in Hive

Tags: mysql, hive, subquery, hiveql, cloudera-cdh

I can run below subquery command in MySQL, but it is not working in Hive. Is the Hive format different for subquery from MySQL?

Question:

Write query in hive that shows all orders belonging to a certain day. This day is when the most orders were placed. select data from orders_sqoop

```
select * 
from orders_sqoop 
where order_date = (select order_date from orders_sqoop 
                    group by order_date 
                    order by count(order_id) desc 
                    limit 1);
```

I see below output in hive (cloudera cdh)

```
NoViableAltException(226@[400:1: precedenceEqualExpression : ( (left= precedenceBitwiseOrExpression -> $left) ( ( KW_NOT precedenceEqualNegatableOperator notExpr= precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) 
   -> ^( KW_NOT ^( precedenceEqualNegatableOperator $precedenceEqualExpression $notExpr) ) | ( precedenceEqualOperator equalExpr= precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) 
   -> ^( precedenceEqualOperator $precedenceEqualExpression $equalExpr) | ( KW_NOT KW_IN LPAREN KW_SELECT )=> ( KW_NOT KW_IN subQueryExpression ) 
   -> ^( KW_NOT ^( TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR ^( TOK_SUBQUERY_OP KW_IN ) subQueryExpression $precedenceEqualExpression) ) | ( KW_NOT KW_IN expressions ) 
   -> ^( KW_NOT ^( TOK_FUNCTION KW_IN $precedenceEqualExpression expressions ) ) | ( KW_IN LPAREN KW_SELECT )=> ( KW_IN subQueryExpression ) 
   -> ^( TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR ^( TOK_SUBQUERY_OP KW_IN ) subQueryExpression $precedenceEqualExpression) | ( KW_IN expressions ) 
   -> ^( TOK_FUNCTION KW_IN $precedenceEqualExpression expressions ) | ( KW_NOT KW_BETWEEN (min= precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) KW_AND (max= precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) ) 
   -> ^( TOK_FUNCTION Identifier["between"] KW_TRUE $left $min $max) | ( KW_BETWEEN (min= precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) KW_AND (max= precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) ) 
   -> ^( TOK_FUNCTION Identifier["between"] KW_FALSE $left $min $max) )* | ( KW_EXISTS LPAREN KW_SELECT )=> ( KW_EXISTS subQueryExpression ) 
   -> ^( TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR ^( TOK_SUBQUERY_OP KW_EXISTS ) subQueryExpression ) );])
        at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
        at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceEqualExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8668)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceNotExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9690)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceAndExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9809)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceOrExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9968)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.expression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6584)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.atomExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6808)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceFieldExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6879)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceUnaryPrefixExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceUnarySuffixExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7324)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceBitwiseXorExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceStarExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7668)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedencePlusExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7828)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceAmpersandExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7988)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceBitwiseOrExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceEqualExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8803)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceNotExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9690)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceAndExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9809)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceOrExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9968)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.expression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6584)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.expression(HiveParser.java:44932)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.searchCondition(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:6530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.whereClause(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:6438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.whereClause(HiveParser.java:44974)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.singleSelectStatement(HiveParser.java:42062)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.selectStatement(HiveParser.java:41720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regularBody(HiveParser.java:41657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:40710)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:40586)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1065)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1473)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:699)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:634)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) FAILED: ParseException line 1:47 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'order_date' 'from' in expression specification
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Wrong results? Please describe what you mean by *not working*.

Comment: i just update the question again with error.. please check it .. thanks

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries ?

Answer (score 0):

Using count() + rank():

```
select * --list all columns here
from
(
select s.*, rank() over(order by cnt desc) rnk 
from
(
select s.*, 
       count(order_id) over(partition by order_date) cnt 
  from orders_sqoop s
) s 
) s where rnk=1
```

Using subquery in the WHERE:

```
select o.* 
  from orders_sqoop o
  where order_date in (select s.order_date from orders_sqoop s group by s.order_date order by count(s.order_id) desc limit 1);
```

Comment: i used subquery in the where but i see below error now

Comment: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line 1:33 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'order_date': Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references.

Comment: @user2774120 Added alias. Try it. But better use first method, anyway it will perform much better

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the **=** to the  **In**  operator

The IN operator is considered a membership type.  The membership type allows you to conduct multiple match tests compactly in one statement

```
select * 
  from orders_sqoop 
 where order_date in  (select order_date from orders_sqoop group by order_date order by count(order_id) desc limit 1);
```

Comment: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line 1:33 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'order_date': Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references.

Comment: You can order by Count(id ) if you don't added in the select